# Connect Wordpress installed in an instance of Google Cloud Platform to Cpanel in another instance of Google Cloud Platform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, cpanel, bitnami

I have a independent wordpress(Bitnami) instance on Google Cloud Platform and another Instance where Cpanel is installed.
How do I access the backend(all files, mails, database etc.) of my Wordpress through cpanel?

Basically I want to control all my files of Wordpress through Cpanel but the problem is that both are installed in difference instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Wordpress instance dashboard by following the below steps:

1. Get the URL or IP of your Wordpress instance
2. Add `/wp-admin` to the end of the URL/IP e.g. `yourwordpressinstance.com/wp-admin`
3. The Wordpress and CPanel instances may use a different username and password so if different get Wordpress username and password to provide them during the login. You should have set these during the installation of Wordpress.
4. When Wordpress login screen shows enter these credentials.

If you get any connection errors you may need to create a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to allow the CPanel instance to communicate with the Wordpress instance.

For further information and troubleshooting you can follow this [documentation](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-introduction/logging-into-wordpress-dashboard) page.